# KVC dot keys issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, kvc

I create class:

```
@interface KVOGame : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *releaseDate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) KVOPlatform *platform;

@end
```

And another one for it property:

```
@interface KVOPlatform : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *platformName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *platformVersion;

@end
```

Then I try to use KVC to get "platformVersion" like this

```
@interface KVOViewController ()

@end

@implementation KVOViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    KVOGame *game = [[KVOGame alloc] init];
    game.name = @"Bayonetta";
    game.releaseDate = @"8.10.2009";
    game.platform.platformName = @"PS3, Xbox360";
    game.platform.platformVersion = @"all versions";

    NSString *identifier = @"platform.platformVersion";

    NSLog(@"%@", [game valueForKey:identifier]);
}
```

And it crash with error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key platform.platformVersion.'

What am I doing wrong?

Update: `valueForKeyPath:` instead of `valueForKey` also does not work - crash anyway.

Comment: Have you `#import KVOGame.h` in your header?

Comment: Where do you instantiate the KVOPlatfrom object? it should be in the implementation of the KVOGame object.  Can you paste the code of that implementation?

Comment: eharo2, that's it! I did not create KVOPlatform instance, and that was the reason! Could you please make answer with this solution? I'll check it. And thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `NSLog(@"%@", [game valueForKeyPath:identifier]);`

I assume `game.platform` never to be created. It is nil